# key-value types about dictionaryWithContentsOfFile

Tags: objective-c, ios

The plist file looks like this:

[image]

then I init a dictionary using this plist,when log the dictionary,it showed likes this(**Please watch the quotation marks, some keys are string type some are not,also happens on values**):

[image]

The time using this dictionary for NSRequest, the app would crash for wrong type of key or value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you log any object, it's description method is called for printing details. In documentaion of description method of [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it's mentioned that-

> This method is intended to produce readable output for debugging
> purposes, not for serializing data.

So don't worry that app will crash after.

Answer (score 1):

They are all strings, just some are formatted with quotations and some are not.  Notice only those with special characters in them have quote marks

This

`NSLog(@"%@", [@{@"client_id" : @"listing_ios", @"urlStr" : @"http://abc.com/access_token"} description]);`

produces this:

> 2013-01-08 13:27:52.855 App[4239:14603] {
>       "client_id" = "listing_ios";
>       urlStr = "http://abc.com/access_token";
>   }